# How often is discrete-time control used in industry?

Tags: control-engineering, control-theory, aerospace-engineering, signal-processing

Although in reality I know that computers handle all systems in discrete time, in my limited industry work experience I've only used continuous-time control system analysis/standard frequency domain design - I briefly took a class in undergrad which touched on the Z-transform, but honestly was in way over my head and know nothing but the broadest of strokes on the subject.

My question: is knowledge of discrete-time control useful for engineers (specifically Aerospace engineers in GN&C) in industry and as such it worth my time to try to take a class and get competent in it? If not, why is continuous time control preferred in industry, and how do we reconcile this with the fact that computers are inherently discrete time? Do we just use continuous-time as an approximation and implement PID controllers etc. in discrete time without thinking about it?

Comment: Apart from PID controllers, are you familiar with discrete time filters?

Comment: At a high level, yes. I suppose discrete time control/filtering is necessary when the dynamics of the system are too fast for it to be a solid assumption that a system is continuous time, i.e. in filtering sensor noise? While in the case of attitude dynamics, for example, the dynamics are so slow that assuming continuous time makes sense? @AJN